# ionic popup - how to apply blur effect on the popup-container but not on the popup itself?

Tags: css

I want to apply the following effect to the background.  Right now, when popup come up, the background fades a bit.  I am trying to make the background blur.  I read that the .popup-container class is the outside background of the popup.  For example changing background-color of the .popup-container to red makes the background red.  I want to make the text or any content that is behind the popup blur .

I am trying to add blur but it does not seem to do anything.  Can you please help?  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPbQNZ

```
.my-popup.popup-container {
  filter: blur(2px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is conditionally apply a class, using `ng-class`, to your entire view. Whether it's your `ion-content` or just some div or whatever. Then you can set the properties of this new class to blur just like you have above with the `.popup-container`.

The condition under which this class gets applied should be whenever your popup is open.

Example [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GooLvx)